# Using linq to select all values from one column based on a distinct second column

Tags: c#, linq

Having some issues with this in Linq. I have a list of records as shown below:

```
var allTeams = new List<AllTeamData>()
{
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Bengals", Conference = "AFC", ConferenceEmail = "AFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Steelers", Conference = "AFC", ConferenceEmail = "AFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Patriots", Conference = "AFC", ConferenceEmail = "AFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Bills", Conference = "AFC", ConferenceEmail = "AFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Dolphins", Conference = "AFC", ConferenceEmail = "AFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Lions", Conference = "NFC", ConferenceEmail = "NFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Bears", Conference = "NFC", ConferenceEmail = "NFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Seahawks", Conference = "NFC", ConferenceEmail = "NFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Cardinals", Conference = "NFC", ConferenceEmail = "NFC@NFL.COM" },
    new AllTeamData { Team = "Vikings", Conference = "NFC", ConferenceEmail = "NFC@NFL.COM" }
};
```

And what I'm trying to do is build a list of records in this form:

```
public class ConferenceData
{
    public string Conference { get; set; }
    public string ConferenceEmail { get; set; }
    public List<string> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is send an email to the specific conference emails with a list of teams in that particular conference.  This is as far as I've been able to get with my linq query:

```
var conferences = (from t in allTeams
                           select new ConferenceData
                           {
                               Conference = t.Conference,
                               ConferenceEmail = t.ConferenceEmail
                           }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Hopefully this all makes sense.  I'm trying to figure out if I need to put together a nested query to pull all the teams and put them in that object list.  Not sure how to go about that.  Any insight would be wonderful.

Comment: take a look at how to use linq `GroupBy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GroupBy` or [group clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

```
var conferences = (from t in allTeams
                  group t by new { t.Conference, t.ConferenceEmail } into g
                  select new ConferenceData {
                      Conference = g.Key.Conference,
                      ConferenceEmail = g.Key.ConferenceEmail,
                      Teams = g.Select(t => t.Team).ToList()
                  }).Tolist();
```

Here is the same using `GroupBy`

```
conferences = allTeams.GroupBy(t => new { t.Conference, t.ConferenceEmail })
               .Select(g => new ConferenceData {
                   Conference = g.Key.Conference,
                   ConferenceEmail = g.Key.ConferenceEmail,
                   Teams = g.Select(t => t.Team).ToList()
               }).Tolist();
```

Comment: I appreciate the info from both of you Grant and Nkosi.  I'll probably go with the group clause usage.  I was looking into that before but wasn't sure how to formulate the clause like you've done it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were writing an SQL query, you'd be trying to group your records by a particular field.

Similarly, LINQ has a `GroupBy` method, allowing you to group your data by conference:

```
var conferences = allTeams.GroupBy(t => t.Conference)
                          .Select(grp => new ConferenceData
                                         {
                                             Conference = grp.Key,
                                             ConferenceEmail = grp.First().ConferenceEmail,
                                             Teams = grp.Select(x => x.Team).ToList()
                                         })
                          .ToList();
```

I've written this in method syntax, since that's what I'm more familiar with, but you could translate it to query syntax (similar to your current query) if you were so inclined.